# Optimal symmetric rank-1 approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, optimization, rank-1-matrices

I want to find $\mathbf{x}$ that minimizes $\|A-\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'\|^2$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is [Frobenius norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm).
Differentiating with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ and setting to $\mathbf{0}$, I get

$$\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{x}=A \mathbf{x}$$

Any idea how to proceed further?

(Per request, here's how I did the derivative)
Let $J=\|A-\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'\|^2=\text{tr}(Y'Y)$ where $Y=A-\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'$

To compute derivative use technique of differentials as in Magnus,Neudecker and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/matrix/)
$$dY(\mathbf{x})=-2\mathbf{x} \mathbf{dx}'$$
$$dJ(Y)=\text{tr}(2Y'dY)$$
substitute definition of $dY$ and $Y$ into above, simplify to get
$$dJ(\mathbf{x})=-4 \text{tr}((A-\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}')'\mathbf{x}\mathbf{dx}')=4\mathbf{x}'(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'-A)'\mathbf{dx}$$
The last expression is a canonical form from which the derivative can be identified as the expression before $\mathbf{dx}$, doing transpose and setting to $\mathbf{0}$ gives the equation above.

Comment: Would you mind showing your work differentiating? The reason I ask is because I wonder why your result should favor a form with only right multiplication. The problem is a symmetric  equation (with respect to $\mathbf{x}$).

Comment: what's the definition of the matrix norm?

Comment: Is $A$ a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Added clarifications. Marvis -- I'm interested in both symmetric and general cases

Comment: I have happened upon your question again. I can say that the definitive answer for the specific and the general case (general rank one approximation) is this: the pair of "largest" singular vectors obtained from the SVD, the Singular Value Decomposition. "Largest" meaning the vectors associated with the largest singular value. This should be standard knowledge--a fact that should be a part of the repertoire of anyone that deals with matrix algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations do not seem quite right. As $Y=A-xx'$, $dY=-dxx'-xdx'$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
dJ&=\operatorname{tr}\,(Y+dY)'(Y+dY)-\operatorname{tr}\,Y'Y\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\,(Y-dxx'-xdx')'(Y-dxx'-xdx')-\operatorname{tr}\,Y'Y\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\,(-Y'dxx' -Y'xdx' - xdx'Y - dxx'Y)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\,(-x'Y'dx -x'Ydx - x'Y'dx - x'Ydx)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\,\left\{-2x'(Y+Y')dx\right\}.
\end{align*}
Hence $J'(x) = -2x'(Y+Y') = -2x'(A+A'-2xx') = -2x'(A+A')+4\|x\|^2x'$. Actually, the calculations can be made much easier if you rewrite $J(x)$ as
\begin{align}
J(x)&=\operatorname{tr}\{(A-xx')'(A-xx')\}
=\operatorname{tr}(AA' -xx'A - A'xx' + xx'xx')\\
&=\|A\|^2 - 2\operatorname{tr}\left(x'\frac{A+A'}{2}x\right) + \|x\|^4\tag{1}
\end{align}
right at the beginning. From this reformulation it is immediate that $J'(x)$ and the extrema of $J$ depend only on the Hermitian part $H=\frac{(A+A')}{2}$ of $A$ but not $A$ itself.

To find the critical points of $J$, set $J'(x)=0$. Then we get $x'H=\|x\|^2x'$. In other words, $x=0$ or if $x\not=0$, $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to a *positive* eigenvalue $\|x\|^2$ of $H$. So you may first find all eigenpairs $(\lambda,v)$ of $H$, ignore the nonpositive eigenvalues and then set $x=\frac{\pm\lambda^{1/2}}{\|v\|}v$ (the sign does not matter, as it will cancel out itself in the product $xx'$). The zero vector and these eigenvectors of $H$ are the critical points of $J$ modulo symmetry. Plug them into $(1)$, we see that the global minimum of $J$ is given by
\begin{cases}
\|A\|^2-\lambda_\max(H)^2 &\ \text{ if } \lambda_\max(H)>0,\\
\|A\|^2&\ \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}

Comment: Presumably the largest eigenvalue has the smallest "leftover" $A-xx'$.

Comment: @RahulNarain Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer but completing it should be straight-forward.

Define the symmetric part of $A$ as $H=(A+A^T)/2$ and skew-symmetric part as $S=(A-A^T)/2$. Then for any symmetric matrix $X$, we have the identity
\begin{align}
||A-X||_F^2=||H-X||_F^2+||S||_F^2
\end{align}
To prove it, substitute $A=H+S$. Now, use the fact $||B||_F^2=trace(B^TB)$ for any matrix $B$ (take $B=A-X$), and also use $H=H^T$, $S=-S^T$.

Thus, finding the closest symmetric $X$ to $A$ is same as finding the closest $X$ to symmetric part $H$ of $A$. In your case, you have additional constraints on $X$. You need $X$ to be rank-one and positive-semidefinite which will then make $X=xx^T$ for some $x$. Please, read the following. The rest should be easy to figure out. I will be update it when I get time.

**Best (not necessary symmetric) rank-one approximation**

You are trying to find the best rank-one approximation of a given matrix $A$. If the SVD of $A=U\Sigma V^T$ is given, then $A_1=\sigma_1u_1v_1^T $, where $u_1$ and $v_1$ correspond to the left and right singular vectors corresponding to the largest singular value $\sigma_1$, is the best rank-one approximation. This is a standard thing and the proof can be found in any standard textbook explaining SVD. But if you are keen on finding the answer using differentiation, then I am not sure how I can help.

Comment: I wanted to fixed it, I didn't know there was a undelete option. Thanks for that!! :):)

Comment: @adamW read the updated answer. You were right I guess

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was thinking. Thank you for typing it up.

Comment: +1 Although this is just a partial answer, I like the line that you split the Frobenius norm into a Hermitian part and a skew Hermitian part.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to show how the norm may be split as the sum of symmetric (Hermitian) and skew symmetric (skew Hermitian).

Let $A = H + S$ with $H = H^*$ and $S = -S^*$. Then
\begin{align}
 \left(H+S\right)\left(H+S\right)^* &= HH^* + HS^* + SH^* + SS^* \\
 &=HH^* -HS + SH + SS^*\\
\end{align}
From the cyclic property of trace, $\operatorname{Trace}(HS) = \operatorname{Trace}(SH)$, and the middle terms cancel in the norm.

Thus we have
$$\Vert A \Vert^2 = \Vert H+S \Vert^2 = \Vert H \Vert^2 + \Vert S \Vert^2$$

The addition of $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'$ then affects only the symmetric portion since it is symmetric. Therefore, the original problem may be simplified using full symmetry, even if $A$ is not itself symmetric, as Dineshdileep noted.

Comment: +1 that was really nice! , you could have added that now one only needs the rank-one approximation of the symmetric part. :)