# Minimal "dominating" rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, rank-1-matrices

Given a matrix ${\bf A} \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$, I would like to find a minimal  rank-$1$ matrix  ${\bf B} \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ such that the Frobenius norm of $ \| {\bf A} - {\bf B} \|_{\text{F}} $ is minimal under the constraint of $ a_{ij} \leq b_{ij}$ for all $i, j \in \{ 1, \dots, n \}$. Also, is there a name for the element-wise  "domination" constraint?

Comment: Not sure how to solve this problem, but you need $A$ to have at least one positive entry, otherwise the minimum does not exist.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271931/339790)

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset{{\bf x}, {\bf y} \in \Bbb R^n} {\text{minimize}} & \left\| {\bf x} {\bf y}^\top - {\bf A} \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 \\ \text{subject to} & {\bf x} {\bf y}^\top \geq {\bf A} \end{array} $$